# Copying an Object type of object into a specific type of object

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make an array of (different) objects (one of those defined in the 'Triangle' class), after messing around with it for a while, this is what I've got:

```
public class ShapeContainer {

    private Object objects [];
    private int _size;
    public static final int init_size = 3;

    public ShapeContainer(ShapeContainer other){
        this.objects = new Object[other.objects.length];
        this._size = other._size;
        for(int i=0; i<_size ;i++){
            if (other.objects[i].getClass().equals(Triangle.class)){
                this.objects[i] = new Triangle(other.objects[i]);
            }
        }   
    }
 }
```

For that to work I've made a new constructor in the Triangle class(note: Triangle is built out of 3 Point objects: Point p1, Point p2, Point p3. Every Point object is built out of 2 double variables: x,y):

```
public Triangle (Object obj){
        this.p1 = new Point(obj.p1);
        this.p2 = new Point(obj.p2);
        this.p3 = new Point(obj.p3);
    }
```

And now the problem is that I can't refer to obj.p1/obj.p2/obj.p3 because "Object obj" isn't recognized as a Triangle object.

So basically, is there a way to make a generic Object recognized as a specific object? If not, how'd you approach this?

Comment: Use the actual type (`Triangle`) for your array variable. If you need to hold multiple different types of shape, create a `Shape` interface or abstract class and use `Triangle extends Shape`.

Comment: Your total approach is off. You should not be using Object type at all. Why not use Point instead?

Comment: You're trying to define the copy constructor in a wrong way. Just use Triangle for your array and you'll be fine. Or define an interface (or an abstract class) and implement/extend those. Also check the instanceof operator (your if conditions is a bit weird).

Comment: When you use a superclass reference to an object and you wish to access the methods and fields of the subclass you need to do a "cast".  This is quite simply `(TheSubclassName)theSuperclassReference`.  (Just don't fall into the trap of believing that a cast "converts" an object from one type to another.  The object must already be the cast-to type.)

Comment: @HotLicks: Quite simple an quite dangerous. I'm betting that the OP wants to use bounded generic types. Generics are often useful for eliminating dangerous casts and for allowing for compile-time type checking and error catching.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Even with generics you quite frequently need to use cast.  It's something the OP needs to understand.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - And ease off the guy a bit.  He's struggling to get a grip on object concepts, and not really doing that bad a job of it.

Comment: @HotLicks: how am I being hard on him? Where have I criticized the OP? I thought that I was being hard on you for recommending casting. At this stage, he won't know better, but you should.

Comment: That's right :P I'm still a bit new to it, while there's a specific answer here to what I've asked about, I suppose "cast" is an important concept that I'm still lacking and that would've helped here, time to Google ^^

Comment: @MrGuy: I'm not all that pleased with the accepted answer and still feel that there's a better way, that perhaps this question is really an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Consider telling us more about your over all problem, about the details of the problem and constraints. I still feel in my bones that a better approach should be used.

Comment: Alright, so casting would've indeed hit the spot here and makes it work better than the solution I was looking for, so 'derp' on me, and thanks for opening my eyes to this.

if (objects[i] instanceof Triangle){
 this.objects[i] = new Triangle((Triangle)other.objects[i]);
}

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - "Your total approach is off...  Why not use something you understand even less well?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way, although it's usage is not very clean in my personal opinion. here it is

```
public Triangle(Object obj){
  if (obj instanceof Triangle){
      Triangle other = (Triangle) obj;
      this.p1 = new Point(other.p1);
      this.p2 = new Point(other.p2);
      this.p3 = new Point(other.p3);
  }
...
}
```

Why do I think this is not very clean? Well for starts I have no idea what to do if the object is not a Triangle. You'd have to figure that out, meaning what would you do if that constructor receives an object which is not a Triangle? Throw an exception? Not sure... This normally doesn't happen in methods such as `equals` where the `instanceof` is used often, because then you know you just return `false`.

However, at least you know how you can "recognize an object as triangle".

Hope this helps

Comment: Well, that constructor won't receive that object if that's not a Triangle, meaning that I'd be able to make the exception outside the constructor.
And yes, knowing how to recognize generic objects as specific ones did help a lot, so cheers :)

Comment: @MrGuy: Why don't you make it a `public Triangle(Triangle obj)` in the first place?

Comment: @DarkDust: Because that constructor wouldn't accept an Object for an input, only a Triangle (note that the constructor "public Triangle(Object obj)" that I wanted to use is added in addition to the already existing "public Triangle(Triangle obj)"

Comment: But if you know you only want to feed it `Triangle` objects, it's not a good idea to fight the type system like that. Check the type _before_ calling the constructor and let the caller do the cast. After all, the call doesn't make any sense if you feed it something that is not a `Triangle`. That information is lost if you create a constructor that accepts _anything_.

Comment: (If I chose to stick the the answer given and not simply change it to be used with casts - just hinting that I know the whole thing is wrong), There'd be other constructors (like the one in Triangle) in the other sub-classes (Rectangle, Circle etc) so that each different type of object will have a different 'if' that'll send it to a different sub-class